# Laravel websockets with angular 8

Tags: angular, laravel, pusher

I have a chat application in Angular 8 that receives messages through laravel websockets. This is done with pusher. However, I want my laravel application to act as the receiver without the need of pusher. I did this before using java spring boot where the java application sent messages without the need of an external service. Can I achieve the same in laravel with the use of socket.io/redis or a different service?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel-Websocket which is an alternative for Pusher. They both use the same mechanism. Official document can be found here: [Laravel Websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction)